# Git commit with SSH asking for email

Tags: git, github, ssh, cmd, gitlab

I am trying to commit to my github repository but I keep getting an error message asking me to identify myself by logging in through email and name. I'm using ssh for the commit, my sshconfig and keys are correctly configured. I have also checked the gitconfig file and they seem to be correct as well.. Any ideas?

```
###Gitconfig file
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:imran1005/testhomere.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:ref
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

###Error msg on console win7 cmd while executing git commit:

*** Please tell me who you are.
Run
    git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'TestUser@Asus.(none)')
```

Comment: git config --global user.email

What output do you get?

Comment: I get an empty output

Comment: Just follow the instructions in the error. Apart from being logged in to Github, your git commits should tell who you are. So, fill in those two lines starting `git config` with your details.

Comment: That means your credentials are not set in git config. You need to set email, name & password for your git config.

Comment: I'm using SSH, authentification with RSA keys. I don't have to set email name and password while using commit with ssh

Comment: verify that your URL is set to SSH.

git remote -v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, you need to set `user.email` and `user.name` git configs. This information is stored in the commit, git does not work without them.

> my sshconfig and keys are correctly configured

This is irrelevant, ssh keys are used when you are pushing existing commits to some remote, not when creating new commits.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed you're right, even with SSH commit, email should be configured!